# periodic tasks in Celery 4.0

Tags: python, celery

As I know, since Celery 3.1 decorator `@periodic_task` is depricated.

So I am trying to run an example from celery [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html), and can't realise, what am I doing wrong.

I have the following code in `task_planner.py`:

```
from celery import Celery
from kombu import Queue, Exchange



class Config(object):
    CELERY_QUEUES = (
        Queue(
            'try',
            exchange=Exchange('try'),
            routing_key='try',
        ),
    )
celery = Celery('tasks', 
                backend='redis://', 
                broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')
celery.config_from_object(Config)


celery.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'planner': {
        'task': 'some_task',
        'schedule': 5.0,
    },
}


@celery.task(queue='try')
def some_task():
    print('Hooray')
```

And when I run: `celery -A task_planner worker -l info -B`, I recieve only the following: `[2016-11-27 19:06:56,119: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task planner (some_task)` every 5 sec.

But I am expecting the output 'Hooray'.

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have found the solution.
I had the task:

```
@celery.task(queue='try')
def some_task():
    print('Hooray')
```

I printed it's name:

```
print(some_task)
```

Got the following:

```
<@task: task_planner.some_task of tasks:0x7fceaaf5b9e8>
```

So I just changed the name of the task from `some_task` to `task_planner.some_task` here:

```
celery.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'planner': {
        'task': 'task_planner.some_task',
        'schedule': 5.0,
    },
}
```

And it worked!

```
[2016-11-29 10:09:57,697: WARNING/PoolWorker-3] Hooray
```

**Note**. You should run beat with worker (if task in the same module as beat) and loglevel 'info' in order to see the results:

```
celery -A task_planner worker -B -l info
```