# Celery task not run at the specified time

Tags: python, celery

I created celery task and it should start each hour at the 0th minute, but it does not run.  What doing wrong?

celery

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
import pytz
from celery import Celery
from datetime import datetime
from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

app = Celery('app', broker='amqp://rabbit:5672')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
 sender.add_periodic_task(crontab(minute=0, hour='0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12, \
                        13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24'), 
                        task.s())

@app.task
def task():
  #any code
```

In the terminal, I see this info, but the task is not running

```
[2018-05-09 19:05:16,275: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
```

Comment: Did you started your Celery instance? Something like that: `celery -A my_project worker -l info`. You need to have 2 terminal opened, Celery and Celery Beat.

Comment: Yes, but I run a command: celery -A proj worker -B -l info

Comment: usually I use another approach with periodic celery tasks - try my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your task code to something like this:

```
from celery.task import periodic_task
from celery.schedules import crontab

@periodic_task(
    run_every=(crontab(minute='*/60')),
    name="task_name")
def run_some_task():
    '''some code'''
```

Comment: @Denis Azi edited my answer, check it again. And this works for Celery v3.2, hope it still works for v4+, but I can't guarantee that.

Comment: @ Denis Azi hmm, according to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832819/periodic-tasks-in-celery-4-0?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa that decorator indeed is deprecated... :/ That means you have to search some another solution if you are using a newer Celery version.